# Проблема с итератором после вызова erase

Tags: stl

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так с удалением по итератору в блоке else?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
#include <set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void parse(string str, multimap<int, int> &myMap)
 {
int pos = str.find('-');
string str1 = str.substr(0, pos);
str = str.substr(pos + 1, (str.size() - 1));
multimap<int, int>::iterator it1;
it1 = myMap.insert(pair<int, int>(atoi(str1.c_str()), atoi(str.c_str())));
for (auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();++it)
{

    if ((it1->first == it->first) && (it1->second > (it->second)))
    {
        it = myMap.erase(it);

    }
    else
    {

        it=myMap.erase(it1);


    }

}
}
   void sort(multimap<int, int> &myMap)
{
    set<int>mySet;
    for (auto it_map = myMap.begin(); it_map != myMap.end(); ++it_map)
        mySet.insert(it_map->second);

    for (auto it_set = mySet.crbegin(); it_set != mySet.crend(); ++it_set)
        for (auto it_map = myMap.begin(); it_map != myMap.end(); ++it_map)

        {
            if (*it_set == it_map->second)
                cout << it_map->first << "-" << *it_set << endl;
        }
}


  int main()
 {
multimap<int, int>myMap;
set<int>myset;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    parse(str, myMap);
}
sort(myMap);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае Вы, после ввода строки вида `ключ-значение`, парсите ее и заносите в карту. Т.е. в карте у Вас только одна пара. Для этой пары Вы создаете итератор `it1`. После чего начинаете в цикле перебирать все значения карты посредством итератора `it`. Но у Вас в карте всего **одно** значение. И `it` всегда будет равен `it1`. Поэтому **всегда** будет исполняться блок `else`, который приводит к удалению пары `ключ-значение` из Вашей карты. Вы удаляете единственное, на что ссылается Ваш итератор, от которого зависит Ваш цикл. Итератор `it` становится недействительным. Какое он примет значение и как надолго зависнет цикл - никто не угадает. А также еще ко всему прочему в разных версиях C++ возвращаются разные значения при использовании метода `erase` в картах.

Если Вам необходимо, чтобы в карте оставался только результат с наибольшим значением, то, во-первых, Вам не нужна multimap. В этом и разница между map и multimap - остается только одна пара с одним ключом. Во-вторых, для поиска ключа в карте (см. `parse`) цикл Вам не нужен. Есть уже готовый `find`. Также, если уж используете C++ и его стандартные библиотеки, то обратите внимание на `stoi` (и т.п.) вместо `atoi`.

Какую роль должна выполнять Ваша функция сортировки - не знаю. Но если она должна вывести пары из карты, отсортированными по значению в обратном порядке, то, с этим она справляется.

В целом, откорректированный код выглядит **[так](http://ideone.com/Sf4CMI)**:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<set>

void parse(std::string str, std::map<int, int> &myMap)
{
    size_t pos = str.find('-');
    std::string str1 = str.substr(0, pos);
    str = str.substr(pos + 1, (str.size() - 1));
    if(myMap.find(std::stoi(str1))!=myMap.end()
        || myMap[std::stoi(str1)] < std::stoi(str))
        myMap[std::stoi(str1)] = std::stoi(str);
}
void sort(std::map<int, int> &myMap)
{
    std::set<int>mySet;
    for(auto&it_map:myMap)mySet.insert(it_map.second);
    for (auto it_set = mySet.crbegin(); it_set != mySet.crend(); ++it_set)
        for(auto&it_map:myMap)
            if (*it_set == it_map.second)
                std::cout << it_map.first << "-" << *it_set << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int>myMap;
    std::set<int>myset;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        parse(str, myMap);
    }
    sort(myMap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы при добавлении в карту, если такой ключ есть, то добавлять пару "ключ-значение" с большим значением.